# VB.NET Upcasted ByRef behaves like ByVal

Tags: vb.net, casting, byref

I ran into a weird situation. The code below fails, because disposed object is still trying to be accessed by the calling sub, even though the called sub has set passed param to a new value.

```
Sub Foo(ByRef astream as Stream)
    'do stuff
    astream.Dispose()
    astream = New MemoryStream()
End Sub

Sub Other()
    Dim memstream as New MemoryStream()
    Foo(CType(memstream, Stream))
    memstream.Position = 0' <- FAILS with Object Disposed!
End Sub
```

This however succeeds:

```
Sub Foo(ByRef astream as MemoryStream)
    'do stuff
    astream.Dispose()
    astream = New MemoryStream()
End Sub

Sub Other()
    Dim memstream as New MemoryStream()
    Foo(memstream)
    memstream.Position = 0' <- This works now!
End Sub
```

So, why does the first one not work when upcasting is involved, and the second one works?

EDIT: Forgot to mention that I am using June Roslyn CTP for VS 2013 (in case it's a bug there).

Thanks.

Comment: +1 I'm using VS 2010 and the behaviour is the same.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thank you for clarifying this. I guess it's by design then. But why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  Foo(CType(memstream, Stream))
```

The CType() expression generates a temporary variable.  That's the one that gets updated.  In other words, the compiler generates code like this:

```
  Dim $Temp = CType(memstream, Stream)
  Foo($Temp)
```

Clearly that won't get your *memstream* variable updated.  You'll need a named variable instead:

```
  Dim temp = CType(memstream, Stream)
  Foo(temp)
  memstream = temp
```

Or just completely avoid using CType() since it is not necessary.  You avoid this kind of lossage by using a Function instead of a Sub:

```
  Function Foo(ByVal astream as Stream) As MemoryStream
     ''do stuff
     astream.Dispose()
     Return New MemoryStream()
  End Function
```

Albeit that this is fairly strange code.

Last but not least, you can get the compiler to emit a diagnostic for this.  Project + Properties, Compile tab, Warnings configuration section.  Change "Implicit conversion" from None to Warning.  It however tends to be a noisy warning, typical VB.NET code has a lot of implicit conversions.

Comment: Thank you very much! That explains it! I cannot use your function suggestion, because my actual code is more complex than what I put here and it already is a function that returns something else, so I cannot return a stream from it. I guess I will stick with declaring a new named variable as you suggested.

Comment: Oh, as an aside... Would it behave any differently if DirectCast was used instead?

Comment: No, that's still an expression.  You keep poking at the need to cast, it strongly suggests you really should be using a Function instead.  As written in your snippet, the argument you pass can only ever be a Stream or a MemoryStream.  Anything else is going to bark at you.

Comment: I see. Thank you. Well, in my case it can also be FileStream too. I just did not include it in my sample not to make it too complicated.